# Setting up dm-rails with Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-datamapper, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How can I get dm-rails to play well with the rest of the Rails 3.2 stack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DM 1.3 beta seems to work with 3.2.1, at least for the demo dm_rails app.

I had to comment out two "active_record" lines in config/environments/development.rb

To update to the 1.3 beta I deleted my Gemfile.lock file, specified the git repository for each dm gem (below), and then ran a bundle install.

```
gem 'dm-core', git: 'https://github.com/datamapper/dm-core'
gem 'dm-active_model', git: 'https://github.com/datamapper/dm-active_model.git'
gem 'dm-validations', git: 'https://github.com/datamapper/dm-validations.git'
gem 'dm-rails', git: 'https://github.com/datamapper/dm-rails.git'
gem 'dm-migrations', git: 'https://github.com/datamapper/dm-migrations'
gem 'dm-types', git: 'https://github.com/datamapper/dm-types'
gem 'dm-constraints', git: 'https://github.com/datamapper/dm-constraints'
gem 'dm-transactions', git: 'https://github.com/datamapper/dm-transactions'
gem 'dm-aggregates', git: 'https://github.com/datamapper/dm-aggregates'
gem 'dm-timestamps', git: 'https://github.com/datamapper/dm-timestamps'
gem 'dm-observer', git: 'https://github.com/datamapper/dm-observer'


gem 'dm-do-adapter', git: 'https://github.com/datamapper/dm-do-adapter'
gem 'dm-sqlite-adapter', git: 'https://github.com/datamapper/dm-sqlite-adapter'
```

After that, the sample project worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Until DataMapper 1.3 is ready with ActiveReload support, you can add the following to your **config/environments/development.rb** to keep reloading the models the old way:

```
config.reload_classes_only_on_change = false
```